# How do I take the text from a array of strings and use it as the text for a button?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, uibutton

I am trying to take an array that has this information: ["Concert", "Coachella", "Date"] and convert the selected array's text to the text of a button. So when I select the "date" option in the array (presented in a table view), that should send that data back to my first VC where the text "date" shows up as the text on a button. For some reason I cannot seem to extract the String from the [String]. Once I extract that String I can set that string as the title text for my UIButton.

Here is the code for where the table view shows options and the user selects an option and that data gets sent to another VC:

```
var delegate : SentDataBack?

@IBOutlet weak var occasionsTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var occasionSearchBar: UISearchBar!

var addedOccasions = ["Coachella", "Concert", "Date"]

var index = 0

var selectedCell = [""]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    occasionsTableView.delegate = self
    occasionsTableView.dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = occasionsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    //let addedOccasions = ["Coachella", "Concert", "Date"]

    cell.textLabel?.text = addedOccasions[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 77/255, blue: 91/255, alpha: 1)

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return(addedOccasions.count)

}

// need to create a method that determines what happens when you click on a cell. what it should do is highlight its text then either store that name into a variable or return what cell text was selected to the data sent back method 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    index = indexPath.row

    selectedCell = [addedOccasions[index]]

}

@IBAction func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    delegate?.dataSentBack(occasionSentBack: selectedCell)
    // sends back selected option
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //can also add a function in here where it says nil, if you want something to happen upon completion of dismiss
}
```

And here is the code that receives that data and is supposed to manipulate a button to display the text of the selected [String]:

```
func dataSentBack(occasionSentBack: [String]) {

configureAddedOccasionButton(selectedOccasion: occasionSentBack)

    // once you get back whatever data is sent back which should be one event, then this area should add that button as selected to the filter list and possibly should add occasion name to occasion array list
}

func configureAddedOccasionButton(selectedOccasion : [String]) {

    //set look of occasion button
    addedOccasion.isHidden = false
    addedOccasion.titleLabel?.text = selectedOccasion.description
    addedOccasion.frame = CGRect(x: 86, y: 33, width: 70, height: 43)
    buttonSelected(buttonPressed: addedOccasion)

}
```

Comment: set the button text in WillAppear or DIdAppear in FirstVc as after dismissing second controller ViewWilApppear is called of firstVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem in setButton title  also if selectedOccasion  is an array of string you need to get text from array by index pass to your delegate

```
 var delegate : SentDataBack?

    @IBOutlet weak var occasionsTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var occasionSearchBar: UISearchBar!

    var addedOccasions = ["Coachella", "Concert", "Date"]

    var index = 0

    var selectedCell = ""


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        occasionsTableView.delegate = self
        occasionsTableView.dataSource = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = occasionsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        //let addedOccasions = ["Coachella", "Concert", "Date"]

        cell.textLabel?.text = addedOccasions[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 77/255, blue: 91/255, alpha: 1)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return(addedOccasions.count)

    }

    // need to create a method that determines what happens when you click on a cell. what it should do is highlight its text then either store that name into a variable or return what cell text was selected to the data sent back method
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        index = indexPath.row

        selectedCell = addedOccasions[index]

    }

    @IBAction func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        delegate?.dataSentBack(occasionSentBack: selectedCell)
        // sends back selected option
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //can also add a function in here where it says nil, if you want something to happen upon completion of dismiss
    }
```

//////////

```
func dataSentBack(occasionSentBack: String) {

    configureAddedOccasionButton(selectedOccasion: occasionSentBack)

    // once you get back whatever data is sent back which should be one event, then this area should add that button as selected to the filter list and possibly should add occasion name to occasion array list
}

func configureAddedOccasionButton(selectedOccasion : String) {

    //set look of occasion button
    addedOccasion.isHidden = false
    addedOccasion.setTitle(selectedOccasion,for: .normal)

    addedOccasion.frame = CGRect(x: 86, y: 33, width: 70, height: 43)
    buttonSelected(buttonPressed: addedOccasion)

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One more question: I have implemented your code and it is displaying the text in the UIButton. However it displays the text as ["Date"] rather than just displaying the word Date. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You should not use `description` on an array to present the result to a user.

Comment: @rmaddy What would I use rather than description?

Comment: It all depends on how you wish to format the data for the user. If you want a simple comma (or some other delimiter) separated list of strings from the array, then use the `joined(separator:)` method of `Array`.

Comment: @ShaliniSingh You will be always passing one string back to the vc

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish if Done button is pressed without selecting any occasion, it will pass the empty string? You should make  selectedCell optional and only update when a value is assigned?

Comment: Yes, he can do this, we just direct him to correct solution